# What's the default GC for jdk1.7.0_11 on Windows and jdk1.7.0_17 on Linux?

Tags: java

I'm using jdk1.7.0_11 on Windows for dev and jdk1.7.0_17 Redhat for prod.

In both cases I was expecting to see G1 as the GC as i thought G1 was the default for Java 7.

However in both cases I see "PS Scavenge and PS MarkSweep" in jconsole.

Is this normal? or is G1 only default in later version?

Thanks

Comment: Java 7 Update 4 made G1 an officially supported GC, but **not** the default GC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Garbage-First Collector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/G1.html) :

> The Garbage-First (G1) garbage collector is fully supported in Oracle
> JDK 7 update 4 and later releases. The G1 collector is a server-style
> garbage collector, targeted for multi-processor machines with large
> memories. It meets garbage collection (GC) pause time goals with high
> probability, while achieving high throughput. Whole-heap operations,
> such as global marking, are performed concurrently with the
> application threads. This prevents interruptions proportional to heap
> or live-data size.

G1 is not default garbage collector in jdk 1.7. The default garbage collector depends upon whether it is java client vm or java server vm.